# finite odd order abelian group property

Tags: abstract-algebra

question: let $|G|=odd $ where $G$ is a finite commutative group then to show every element of $G$ is a square.

**ans 1>** 
 to show that $∀g∈G,∃g_1∈G,g=g_1^2$.

let $g \in G$ then $|g|$   $\big |$ $|G| \implies |g|=2n+1$ for some $n$

$e=g^{2n+1}=g^{2n}.g$ then if i take $g_1 =g^{-n}$ the result holds.

**ans 2>**

consider the homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ definrd by $\phi(g)=g^2$ then $\phi$ is a homomorphism

now $ker{\phi} =\{ g\in G $ $\big|$ $ g^2=e \}$ then $ker (\phi) ={e}$ as no non trivial element of $G$ belong to $G$ as $2$ doesnot divide $|G|$

Hence  $G \simeq \phi(G)$ and the result holds.

are both these answers correct?

Comment: They both look fine to me.

Comment: More generally one can give an [easy *conceptual* proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304919/23500) of $$\rm{\bf Theorem}\ \ \ g^n = 1,\,\ (k,n)\mid i\:\Rightarrow\: g^i\ \ is\ a\ k'th\ power\ \ \ [{\bf\ Easy\ k'th\ Power\ Criterion}]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be generalized as follows:

> Lemma: Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and let $m$ be a positive integer such that $(m,n)=1$, then for all $g\in G$, there exists $x\in G$ with $g=x^m$.

The proof is routine and is the same as you did in **ans 1**.

Comment: thanks for the generalization

Comment: Also, the $x$ is unique.

Comment: More generally one can give an [easy *conceptual* proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/304919/23500) of $$\rm{\bf Theorem}\ \ \ g^n = 1,\,\ (k,n)\mid i\:\Rightarrow\: g^i\ \ is\ a\ k'th\ power\ \ \ [{\bf\ Easy\ k'th\ Power\ Criterion}]$$

Comment: @MathGems: Why didn't make your comment as an answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both answers look fine.$\;$